# How to return the response from a javascript file in JQuery .ajax()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm totally new to jQuery and javascript. Not sure if this is a valid question or not. I was reading the source code for the website I'm currently maintaining. At some places in the code, I need to get the responses from users and send them to a PHP file for data processing and return the result. An example may be as below.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "get_date.php",
    data: {month: $('#month').val(), year: $('#year').val()},
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
         console.log(response.date)
    }
    ....
})
```

In the **get_date.php** file I can write something like this:

```
...
echo json_encode($output)
```

Now I want to replace the get_date.php with another javascript file, but **I don't know how to return a JSON object like what I did in the get_date.php file**. I tried the following code but it doesn't work.

```
var output = JSON.stringify(js_object)
console.log(output)
```

Thanks for all the replies! The reason I want to use a js file here is I need to manipulate some HDF5 files specified by the users. As far as I know, php cannot handle HDF5 files easily, but javascript can. I hope this makes the problem clearer.

Any comments would be appreciated!

Comment: Not clear what are you trying to make. Want to replace php script with js script?

Comment: it's quite simple, the stringify method accepts an array or an object or an array of objects or a mixture of all and returns a JSON converted string. This should help: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-work-with-json-in-javascript

Comment: @ulikus, yes, I want to replace the php script with js script. Sorry about the confusion, I've re-edited the question. I don't know how to make the js script return a JSON object to the "success: function (response) {}" part.

Comment: You don't need jQuery https://github.com/you-dont-need-x/you-dont-need-jquery

Comment: a javascript file cannot "return" a value in the same sense that a php file can. In this specific case, the response will be the content of the js file (and it will go to the error callback because javascript isn't valid json.) If you just want json, perhaps a json file would make more sense.

Comment: @ImmortalDude, sorry I didn't explain my question clearly. I was not asking about the stringify method, but how to pass this json object back to the success function.

Comment: @KevinB, thanks for the reply. The reason I want to use a js file here is I need to manipulate some HDF5 files specified by the users. As far as I know, php cannot handle HDF5 files, but javascript can. I'm not sure this makes more sense.

Comment: So you want to replace your backend php file with a JavaScript file, well that won't work with Ajax, because Ajax is a wrapper for xhttp requests, you need a server to communicate with, you can try node scripts running on node js (if you really need JavaScript to be the one manipulating the files) or ditch the Ajax and do it in the same script file/codeblock

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here's where you're stumbling:

> "Now I want to replace the **get_date.php** with another ***javascript*** file"

You see, the **$.ajax(...)** construct in your source-code sends an *asynchronous* request to an *external* host, not "the same computer."  Your computer will construct and send an `HTTP(S)` request to that computer, then proceed immediately with the next JavaScript statement in the program.

However, *at some (unpredictable) future time,* the host will send its reply.  When it does so ... *(hence: "asynchronously ..." the "A" in AJAX ...),* and assuming that the request was `200 OK`, your JavaScript program will execute the `success:` function.

The "new" scenario that you describe is fundamentally different from this – a  *JavaScript* file runs on "your own" computer (therefore: "synchronously"), not "a different" one.  And you simply can't swap one for the other.  You'll have to re-think your design.

Of course, the community here will be happy to assist you.  Tell us more ...

Comment: Thanks! so it is okay to have a php file here, because a php file runs on the external host, but not so for a Javascript file because a js file runs on my own computer? I want to use a javascript file here because I need to work with HDF5 files specified by the users and get a return that can be displayed on the browser. Does this make more sense?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to process files, stored on the client, with client-side JavaScript, then you need to be reading them with [the file API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications) and not involving Ajax at all.

If you want to run JavaScript server side, then you need to configure your server to run it (or replace the server with one designed to run JavaScript (Node.js + ExpressJS is a common choice)). You can't just submit an HTTP request to a JavaScript file that the server is configured to treat like any other static file for delivery direct to the client.